# how to stop PC from sending ICMP of "Destination Unreachable(host administratively prohibited)"

Tags: networking, fedora, firewall, icmp

I'm doing some experiments and measurements. I send some random TCP packets to a laptop(with fedora system), that laptop reacts by sending ICMP packets of type 3 and code 10, which means Destination Unreachable(host administratively prohibited).

I want this laptop stop sending back such ICMP packets, what can I do? thanks

Comment: Look at the firewall rules ...

Comment: @DavidPostill how to do?

Comment: No idea. I don't know Fedora.